# How to achieve in Prisma "Definitely create 1-1 relation but also delete existing relation record if it exists" in one nested query within upsert

Tags: javascript, typescript, orm, prisma

I have three entities of interest in Prisma schema: `Assistant`, `UrlContent` and `UrlContentWebhook`.

Prisma postgres schema:

```js
model Assistant {
  id                     String             @id @default(cuid())
  url_content            UrlContent[]
  ...
}

model UrlContent {
  id                      String             @id @default(cuid())
  awaiting_scrape_webhook UrlContentWebhook?
  assistant_id            String
  ...

  assistant  Assistant @relation(fields: [assistant_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  @@unique([assistant_id, url])
}

model UrlContentWebhook {
  id             String   @id @default(cuid())
  url_content_id String   @unique
  ...

  url_content UrlContent @relation(fields: [url_content_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}
```

I am trying to update assistant with upserted `UrlContent`, and for each `UrlContent` that is being updated (instead of created) I am trying to delete connected `UrlContentWebhook` (`awaiting_scrape_webhook`) if the connection exists, and always create new `UrlContentWebhook`. I would like to accomplish this with one query, without first traversing all the records that should be updated and then deleting its connected records.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

This query fails when there is `UrlContent` without `UrlContentWebhook`; with this error:

```
Invalid `prisma.assistant.update()` invocation:

An operation failed because it depends on one or more records that were required but not found. No 'UrlContentWebhook' record was found for a nested delete on relation 'UrlContentToUrlContentWebhook'.
```

and it runs succesfully on `UrlContent` with `UrlContentWebhook`.

```js
const updatedAssistant = await ctx.prisma.$transaction(async (tx) => {
    const assistant = await tx.assistant.update({
        where: {
            id: assistantId,
        },
        data: {
            url_content: {
                // https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#nested-writes
                // for each url in urls, create a new UrlContent or update the existing one if it exists
                upsert: urls.map((url) => {
                    return {
                        create: {
                            awaiting_scrape_webhook: {
                                // when creating a new UrlContent,
                                // then create UrlContentWebhook for this newly created UrlContent
                                create: {},
                            },
                            url: url,
                        },
                        update: {
                            awaiting_scrape_webhook: {
                                // !! This is the part that is not working, for which I need the solution !!
                                // when updating existing UrlContent,
                                // then first delete any potential UrlContentWebhook that is connected to this UrlContent
                                // and then create a new UrlContentWebhook for this UrlContent
                                delete: true,
                                create: {},
                            },
                        },
                        where: {
                            assistant_id_url: {
                                assistant_id: assistantId,
                                url: url,
                            },
                        },
                    };
                }),
            },
        },
        include: {
            url_content: {
                include: {
                    awaiting_scrape_webhook: true,
                },
            },
        },
    });

    return assistant;
});
```